# Pandas: consecutive rows' value change comparison

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a Dataframe with date as index:

### Index             | Opp id | Pipeline_Type |Amount

### 20170104          | 1      |  Null         |   10

### 20170104          | 2      | Sou           |   20

### 20170104          | 3      | Inf           |   25

### 20170118          | 1      | Inf           |   12

### 20170118          | 2      | Null          |   27

### 20170118          | 3      | Inf           |   25

Now I want to calculate number of records(Opp id) for which Pipeline type has changed or amount has changed (+/-diff). Above no of records will be 2 for pipeline_type as well as for amount.

Please help me frame the solution.

Comment: Ankit sorry for the poor edit. I'm new to the community. Made some edits.

Comment: Got the answer. Need to merge with left join then compare consecutive rows using .shift() function.